# Как реализовать рефссылки в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telegram

Как реализовать рефссылки в телеграм боте?
Во многих ботах видел реализовано, например `t.me/store_bot?start=whattomine_bot` 
Т.е. ссылка сразу тебя переносит на какую-либо команду
Хочу реализовать подобное, отслеживать пользователей которые перешли в бота по ссылке от другого пользователя вида: `t.me/my_bot?start= chat.id` приглашающего пользователя.

Ну и следовательно считать сколько определённый `chat.id` пригласил пользователей в бота

Comment: Кстати, не стоит путать chat.id и from.id даже если иногда они совпадают

Answer (score 2):

Этого можно добиться с помощью механизма т.н. «[Внешнего связывания](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking)». Когда пользователь переходит по ссылке вида `https://t.me/<ник_бота>?start=<данные>` и нажимет кнопку «Начать», бот получает команду с переданными данными такого вида:

```
/start <данные>
```

Даже не смотря на то, что в интерфейсе пользователя не будет видно аргумента. Кроме того, пользователь имеет возможность написать команду такого типа вручную.

Обработать её можно, например, с помощью библиотеки [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) вот так.

```
@bot.message_handler(regexp='^/start [A-Za-z0-9_-]+$')
def deep_link(msg):
    arg = msg.text[7:]
    ...
```

Либо встройте обработку в ваш существующий обработчик команды /start. Наверняка он уже имеется.